# Resizable and draggable images inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

How can I make each images resizable and draggable?

Bellow is a small piece of code that allows the user to pick and choose what image he or she would like to display. They can pick both and as many as they want.

What I want to do is for the user to resize and drag the image inside a div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#imajes').change(function() {
    $('.subselector').hide();
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();

  });

  $('.smallimages').hide();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var val = $(this).val();


  $('#dog').on('change', function() {

    $("#bulldogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'bulldog') ? 'block' : 'none');

  });

  $('img').on('click', function() {
    $('#fotos').append('<img class="modal-content" src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '">');
    $('#fotos').draggable();
    $('#imgdisplay').resizable();

  });

});
```

```css
.imgcontainerss {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="fotos">
  <img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" />
</div>

<select id="imajes">
  <option value="">Choose Image</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>

</select>
<select id="dog" name="subselector" class="subselector" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Choose an item</option>
  <option value="bulldog">Bulldog</option>

</select>


<div style='display:none;' id="bulldogimges" class="smallimages">
  <div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
  <div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update fiddle code and added draggable and resizable to image

Need to click on image to enlarge it and resize it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#imajes').change(function() {
    $('.subselector').hide();
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
 
  });
  
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
 
 
$('#dog').on('change', function() {
  
  $("#bulldogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'bulldog') ? 'block' : 'none');

});

$('img').on('click', function() {
    $('#fotos').append('<div class="imgdrag"><img class="modal-content" src="' + $(this).attr('src')+ '"/></div>'); $('.imgdrag').draggable();
$('#fotos').droppable();
            $('.modal-content').resizable();


});

  
  
});
```

```css
.imgcontainerss{
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

<div id="fotos" ><img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" /></div>

<select id="imajes">
        <option value="">Choose Image</option>
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
       
    </select> <select id="dog" name="subselector" class="subselector" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Choose an item</option>
  <option value="bulldog">Bulldog</option>
 
</select>


<div style='display:none;' id="bulldogimges" class="smallimages">
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div></div>
```

Comment: An answer should include some explanation in addition to any code sample. Code only answers do not help as much.

Comment: i ran into another problem when i click on the second image to show both images drag at the same time instead of one at a time

Comment: I have checked when click on second image it enlarge and show at top and we can resize it.

Comment: why is it moving together then