# divs drag together instead of separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i ran into a small problem when i was trying to figure out how to do draggable and resizable now when i get two or more images they become one big draggable i wanted to do a separately draggable each image.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#imajes').change(function() {
    $('.subselector').hide();
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
 
  });
  
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
 
 
$('#dog').on('change', function() {
  
  $("#bulldogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'bulldog') ? 'block' : 'none');

});

$('img').on('click', function() {
    $('#fotos').append('<img class="modal-content" src="' + $(this).attr('src')+ '">'); $('#fotos').draggable();
           $('.modal-content').resizable();


});

  
  
});
```

```css
.imgcontainerss{
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

<div id="fotos" ><img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" /></div>

<select id="imajes">
        <option value="">Choose Image</option>
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
       
    </select> <select id="dog" name="subselector" class="subselector" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Choose an item</option>
  <option value="bulldog">Bulldog</option>
 
</select>


<div style='display:none;' id="bulldogimges" class="smallimages">
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div></div>
```

[Resizable and draggable images inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404968/resizable-and-draggable-images-inside-div/41405376#41405376)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try updated code to not move toggether:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#imajes').change(function() {
    $('.subselector').hide();
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
 
  });
  
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
 
 
$('#dog').on('change', function() {
  
  $("#bulldogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'bulldog') ? 'block' : 'none');

});

$('img').on('click', function() {
    $('#fotos').append('<div class="imgdrag"><img class="modal-content" src="' + $(this).attr('src')+ '"/></div>'); $('.imgdrag').draggable();
$('#fotos').droppable();
            $('.modal-content').resizable();



});

  
  
});
```

```css
.imgcontainerss{
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

<div id="fotos" ><img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" /></div>

<select id="imajes">
        <option value="">Choose Image</option>
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
       
    </select> <select id="dog" name="subselector" class="subselector" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Choose an item</option>
  <option value="bulldog">Bulldog</option>
 
</select>


<div style='display:none;' id="bulldogimges" class="smallimages">
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div></div>
```